# Using Fiddler to Find Out What Is Being Passed In DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth, fiddler

I'm using Fiddler in order to see what is being passed during the "handshaking" process in DotNetOpenAuth. I'm testing out Twitter's API (although I don't think that's relevant). I'm trying to see what is being sent when my application makes server to server calls to Twitter's API.

When I run a trace in Fiddler, I see there is a "Tunnel to" "api.twitter.com"- however when I look at the inspectors it is not at all clear what is being sent and what is being received.

I know I'm getting some tokens back, but should I be able to see my Twitter request and response via Fiddler?

Comment: It sounds like it's using SSL which would make sense, you'll have to setup fiddler to decrypt SSL traffic. There's plenty of info on how to do that online. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Comment: @BenCr it seems like I'm doing that - when I look at the raw response I see a message that says this-- "
Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list." - Plus information about the server certificate-- but I don't see the token which it's getting back.

Answer (score 0):

*(for closure - adding answer to question with correct documentation link)*

The best approach would be to turn on logging and use the logs to trace what is coming and going between your code and twitter.

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Logging-and-debugging